# About visual studio folder

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, web

I just made a bad mistake which is I moved my Visual Studio folder to another path, and now I can't find the launching file and I can't make the installer locate it too because there is no option to locate already installed one.

Can you help me to make my Visual Studio working again in it's new path?
I hope you can...
Edit: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: What version of VS?

Comment: VS2019 was originally executed from here on my PC: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Comment: Just move it all back to the right place.

Comment: If you can undo the move do that.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I found it but is says error and reinstall software

Comment: If what you're saying is accurate - that you did NOTHING more than move your "Visual Studio folder" (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio`) to "another path" ... then you SHOULD simply be able to move it back.  Otherwise, your best bet is probably to reinstall.  MSVS has lots of "moving parts" ... and there's no telling how much damage you've actually done, and how much work to undo it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state which version of Visual Studio, but for me my shortcut to the executable is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

There might be too much data for an "undo" to be successful. So if you are using **Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition** you should be able to move it back to the above folder structure.

Comment: this executable file is giving me an error (didn't find other component please reinstall the software.

Comment: @TharwatMella Then your system seems to be more messed. I can’t see that we can help you.